# Since animation can only be set as background, how to have a background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have ImageButtons that take a background, this background provides a standard shape for my buttons.  But I have a special image button that is an animation. Animations only work if they are placed using setBackground.

So, how can I have my normal button background, and still have the animation graphically nested inside of it? Is there some kind of drawable that would let me nest a background?

The reason I need a separate background is the onPress states that it provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this with a FrameLayout so that I can have the original imagebutton and the animated imageview on top of each other